# How to forward propagate/fill a specific value in a Pandas DataFrame Column/Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a boolean column in a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
True
False
False
False
False
True
False
False
False
```

I want to forward propagate/fill the True values n number of times. e.g. 2 times:

```
True
True
True
False
False
True
True
True
False
```

the `ffill` does something similar for `NaN` values, but I can't find anything for a specific value as described. Is the easiest way to do this just to do a standard loop and just iterate over the rows and modify the column in question with a counter?

Each row is an equi-distant time series entry

**EDIT:**

The current answers all solve my specific problem with a bool column, but one answer can be modified to be more general purpose:

```
>> s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3])
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    1
6    2
7    3

>> condition_mask = s == 2
>> s.mask(~(condition_mask)).ffill(limit=2).fillna(s).astype(int)

0    1
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    5
5    1
6    2
7    2
```

Comment: You can use the following instead of `condition_mask`. `s.mask(s.ne(2)).ffill(limit=2).fillna(s).astype(int)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use `ffill` but first you have to mask the `False` values

```
s.mask(~s).ffill(limit=2).fillna(s)
```

---

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
8    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

For 2 times you could have:

```py
s = s | s.shift(1) | s.shift(2)
```

You could generalize to n-times from there.

Comment: interesting approach, this would only work for boolean columns though, which works for me, is there a more general way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try with `rolling`

```
n = 3
s.rolling(n, min_periods=1).max().astype(bool)
Out[147]: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
8    False
Name: s, dtype: bool
```

Comment: so if i understand this correctly, this calculates the rolling max, so converts the bool series to float, and then keeps a n-sized window of max values, and then converts back to bool?